# 3 days hut to hut hike Chamonix area mid september

Tags: hiking, national-parks, huts

We are a couple (34,38) looking for a three days hike in Chamonix area.
We are interested in a hut-to-hut hike, thought about Vanoise national park or Mont Blanc area, looking for something of medium difficulty.
Traveling on mid September.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The "Tour de Mont Blanc" is a famous trek around the whole Mont Blanc massive. My wife and me walked it some years ago, accommodation was partly in huts, partly in some "Gîtes d'étape" or cheap hostels. I am sure you can just pick a 3 days section out of the tour which has the difficulty you prefer. You can find comprehensive information about the tours and the huts [on this web site](http://www.autourdumontblanc.com).